Is the set of probability measures with zero mean and unit variance closed under the weak topology?
Consider the set of all Borel probability measures on $\mathbb R$ that have mean zero and unit variance. Is it closed under the weak convergence topology?
For sure, it would be true if we were considering a compact domain as there $f:x\mapsto x$ and $g:x \mapsto x^2$ are continuous and bounded. In particular, the mappings $P\mapsto \langle P, f\rangle$ and $P\mapsto\langle P, g\rangle$ are continuous wrt the weak convergence, so the level sets are closed. But for unbounded domains, then $f$ and $g$ are unbounded, so I am not sure whether still we have closedness...

Not sure about the terminology, but couldnt you write $
{ \mu: \ \int_{\mathbb R^n} |x|^2 d\mu \le 1 }
= \bigcap_{R > 0 }{ \mu: \ \int_{B_R(0)} |x|^2 d\mu \le 1 }
$? The latter set should be weakly closed as an intersection of weakly closed sets. Equality follows from monotone convergence.

Oh sorry it was meant to be $\mathbb R$... I'll fix it

No, this is not true. In fact, the set is not even closed under the total variation norm topology, which is stronger than the topology of weak convergence. Indeed, for each $n \geq 1$, let,
$$\mu_n = (1-\frac{2}{n})\delta_0+\frac{1}{n}\chi_{[-k_n-1,-k_n]\cup[k_n,k_n+1]}\lambda$$
where $k_n=\frac{-1+\sqrt{2n-\frac{1}{3}}}{2}$ and $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure. It is easy to check $\mu_n$ all have mean $0$ and unit variance. However, under total variation norm, it is easy to see that,
$$\mu_n \to \delta_0$$
which, of course, has variance $0$ instead of unit variance.
